# How to get resolve {{searchResult.url}} in Webscraping

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'v been having trouble scraping the following website content https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search#!?showOnly=openAccess&material=Bowls&era=8000-2000%20B.C.&offset=0&pageSize=0&perPage=20&sortBy=Relevance&sortOrder=asc&searchField=All

I want to get href from a tags using this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import bs4
import requests
 # url of website
my_url='https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search#!?showOnly=openAccess&material=Bowls&era=8000-2000%20B.C.&offset=0&pageSize=0&perPage=20&sortBy=Relevance&sortOrder=asc&searchField=All'

 # opening up connection by using uReq and store in variable 
uClient=uReq(my_url)
page_html=uClient.read()           # read website html and store in variable
uClient.close()                    # closing of connection

 # parsing html page
page_soup=soup(page_html , "html.parser")

#info
con2=page_soup.find_all("a" , {"class" : "result-card__link js-advanced-form"})
for link in con2:
    href=link.get('href')
    print(href)
```

But i got this result: {{searchResult.url}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a dynamic page. best way to get results here would be to go straight to the data source via API. I dumped it into a dataframe, but you can do what you'd like, and just pull out the href by calling that column (I don't know which url you were wanting).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import math
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://www.metmuseum.org/api/collection/collectionlisting'

payload = {
'artist': '',
'department': '',
'era': '8000-2000 B.C.',
'geolocation': '',
'material': 'Bowls',
'offset': '0',
'pageSize': '0',
'perPage': '100',
'searchField': 'All',
'showOnly': 'openAccess',
'sortBy': 'Relevance',
'sortOrder': 'asc'}



jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
print ('Aquired page 1...')

df = json_normalize(jsonData['results'])

total_collections = jsonData['totalResults']
totalPages = math.ceil(total_collections / 100)


for page in range(1, totalPages):
    payload = {
            'artist': '',
            'department': '',
            'era': '8000-2000 B.C.',
            'geolocation': '',
            'material': 'Bowls',
            'offset': '%s' %(page*100),
            'pageSize': '0',
            'perPage': '100',
            'searchField': 'All',
            'showOnly': 'openAccess',
            'sortBy': 'Relevance',
            'sortOrder': 'asc'}

    jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
    print ('Aquired page %s...' %(page+1))
    temp_df = json_normalize(jsonData['results'])

    df = df.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.head(5).to_string())
  accessionNumber artist culture                  date                    description                                 galleryInformation                                              image                            largeImage                                             medium                               regularImage                                         teaserText                                     title                                                url
0        36.1.117                 ca. 3850–2960 B.C.\n                                                                       Not on view  https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/eg/mobi...  eg/web-large/36.1.117_EGDP010235.jpg                                            Pottery  eg/web-additional/36.1.117_EGDP010235.jpg  <p>Date: ca. 3850–2960 B.C.\n<br/>Accession Nu...                   Bowl with flattened rim  /art/collection/search/552185?&searchField=All...
1      1992.252.1          Japan                  None  Accession Number: 1992.252.1   On view at The Met Fifth Avenue in <a href='ht...  https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/as/mobi...              as/web-large/DP23088.jpg  Earthenware with cord-marked and incised decor...              as/web-additional/DP23088.jpg                <p>Accession Number: 1992.252.1</p>  “Flame-rimmed” deep bowl (kaen doki)\n\n  /art/collection/search/44905?&searchField=All&...
2         33.4.41                   ca. 3850–2960 B.C.                                                                       Not on view  https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/eg/mobi...   eg/web-large/33.4.41_EGDP011262.jpg                                            Pottery   eg/web-additional/33.4.41_EGDP011262.jpg  <p>Date: ca. 3850–2960 B.C.<br/>Accession Numb...                                 Deep bowl  /art/collection/search/558199?&searchField=All...
3       12.181.38                   ca. 3100–2649 B.C.                                                                       Not on view  https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/eg/mobi...            eg/web-large/12-181-38.jpg                    Travertine (Egyptian alabaster)            eg/web-additional/12-181-38.jpg  <p>Date: ca. 3100–2649 B.C.<br/>Accession Numb...                              Shallow bowl  /art/collection/search/547548?&searchField=All...
4         99.4.55                 ca. 3850–2960 B.C.\n                                                                       Not on view  https://images.metmuseum.org/CRDImages/eg/mobi...   eg/web-large/99.4.55_EGDP010319.jpg                                            Pottery   eg/web-additional/99.4.55_EGDP010319.jpg  <p>Date: ca. 3850–2960 B.C.\n<br/>Accession Nu...                              Shallow bowl  /art/collection/search/552308?&searchField=All...
```